# How to get view (ImageView ) using id in android

Tags: android, android-layout, view, imageview, android-imageview

**Update**

i know i can use array or list for it but i want to use an efficient way for it with out using arrays or collection thanks to all of you
special thanks to mussharapp

hi i want to access Imageview using its id 
for example i have an imageview which is created using loop like

```
for(int i=1;i<10;i++) { 
      Imageview mv=new ImageView(this);
        mv.setid(i); 
       // and so on for image properties 
             }
```

now i want to get all images which i have created in loop how i can get these images is there any way using id or some thing else ???

the same problem i am facing

Comment: Are you adding these image views to any layout or something???

Comment: How about using `List<ImageView>` ?

Comment: i am creating imageviews using  'ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflate.inflate(
      R.layout.ani_image_view, null);'

Comment: every time imageview drawlabe  is changed after some time now i want to access old images how to get

Comment: @NoamanAkram please update your question and describe clearly and in detail what you are doing and what you want..

Answer (score 1):

declare a `private` arraylist:

```
private ArrayList<Imageview> images = new ArrayList<Imageview>();
```

then store all your views into that list:

```
for(int i=1;i<10;i++) { 
    Imageview mv=new ImageView(this);
    mv.setid(i); 
    // and so on for image properties
    images.add(mv); 
}
```

Finally, you can get them based on position/id (since `position == id`):

```
ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
```

Remember to clear list when done or `onDestroy()`.

```
images.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are sure that the image view id's will be unique you can do something like this

```
//Your code
for(int i=1;i<10;i++) { 
      Imageview mv=new ImageView(this);
        mv.setid(i); 
       // and so on for image properties 
             }

//...
List<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    ImageView mv = (ImageView) findViewById(i);
    drawables.add(mv.getDrawable());
}
```

Not sure what you are trying to do is efficient. You are probably better off with the other suggestions they have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set Array of images with its path and then you can use it...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an array of ImageViews.

```
ImageView[] mImageViews = new ImageView[10];
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++) { 
            mImageViews[i] = new ImageView(this); 
        }
```

And access these like mImageViews[2] or mImageViews[5]